# MySQL Datetime Less Than Functionality

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table with some datetime columns.  I need to be able to select the rows between two datetimes on the same column.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM `t_punchcards`
WHERE UserID = 'root' AND
      PunchInTime > CAST('01-01-2015 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AND
      PunchInTime < CAST('03-06-2015 23:59:59' AS DATETIME);
```

For some strange reason, this yields no results.  I have tried using BETWEEN, I've tried not casting to datetime from string (just use a raw string), I've tried <= >=.  I'm very lost.

As a sidenote, removing the second constraint (AND PunchInTime < CAST('03-06-2015 23:59:59' AS DATETIME); WILL in fact yield results.  Are you not allowed to do a comparison against the same column in the same query?

Here's an example of the table:

```
UserID(varchar)      PunchInTime(datetime)    PunchOutTime(datetime)
root                 01-01-2015 8:02:31       01-01-2015 12:35:51
```

Comment: mysql `datetime` as `01-01-2015 8:02:31 ` ? are you sure about it ?

Comment: Thats not the datetime format for MySQL, you're beating the wrong drum

Comment: Your syntax is MySQL, so I'm remove the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I forgot that the datetime format is not dd-mm-yyyy, it is yyyy-mm-dd.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this logic as:

```
WHERE UserID = 'root' AND
      PunchInTime > DATE('2015-01-01') AND
      PunchInTime < DATE('2015-03-07')
```

Note that I removed the time component from the second value.  This is a cleaner way of making the comparison, unless you really want to treat the last few milliseconds of a day differently from the rest of the time during the day.

Note:  If you are not using MySQL or you want more compliant code, the following works in more databases:

```
WHERE UserID = 'root' AND
      PunchInTime > CAST('2015-01-01' as DATETIME) AND
      PunchInTime < CAST('2015-03-07' as DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the issue. I'm curious as to why you cannot be more restrictive with the time, however. Is there a reason for this? It's not an issue now, but for future reference it would be nice to know.  edit:  Ah, I was using the wrong format dd-mm-yyyy..

Comment: You *can* be more restrictive with the time.  It is just unnecessary when you seem to want date comparisons.